# What is this symbol on my necklace?

Tags: roman, symbolism, history, italy

I bought this pendant in Italy around 10 years ago, I think from Rome. 
I’ve always been curious as to what the bird with the sun above it (etched onto the red glossy background) represents. I was a child at the time... I only picked it up because I thought it looked cool without really asking what it is. Could it be a specific symbol in Italian culture/history?
[image: necklace]

Comment: Welcome to SE:Mythology!  *(Don't forget to formally accept a response if in answers your question:)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the [dove](https://www.preachingsymbols.com/dove.html) with a halo, as a [christian symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doves_as_symbols#Christianity) for the Holy Spirit or the soul.

The [colour red](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red#In_religion) is associated with the blood of Christ and with the Holy Spirit.

The fact that you bought it in Italy (Rome) supports this, as there is a big christian community as well as many pilgrims and tourists visiting Rome and Vatican City.

Comment: Welcome to Mythology. Thanks for contributing!